# How to write conditional class in html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I would like to have no id when `comment` is nil.
This is the actual code (doesn't works). The problem is that even when `comment` is not nil it goes in the second condition and send me the empty ID

```
<div id="<% comment ? 'id1-<%= comment.id %>-container' : '' " class="class2">
```

Comment: Asking questions on Stack Overflow is not a substitute to learning the basics of a programming language (in this case ERB) or even using a search engine. Please find a tutorial in how to use ERB and get a grasp of the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% if comment.nil? %> 
  <div class="class2" />
<% else %>
  <div id="id1-#{comment.id}-container" class="class2" />
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would like to do it in one line is why I could not find the solution. But I think I will take your solution and going through other things. Thank you for your quick answer !

Comment: It's quite easy doing a one-liner, take a look at the duplicated question. I just find using the ternary operator inside `erb` to be absolutely hideous, but that's just my opinion.